# Animate css effect - JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a table. The row is given specific height and overflow is set to hidden. On click, the row will expand down showing hidden contents. I have done this using `toggle` method. The styling is altered to show contents. This works perfect. But I want to add some sliding animation effect to this. The expansion of row happens immediately after I click it. Instead, I want this to happen in a smooth animated format, like in some jQuery menus. Also I want to hide one open row if another row expands.

You can see a working fiddle **[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/blasteralfred/GbWjs/)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a way how to do that:
- Set the height of 40px via jQuery, but before doing that, calculate the height of the
'opened' element.
-Than just animate on click.

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/vce6W/)

```
var cl4h = $('.class4').height(); // get the height of the opened .class4

$('.class4').css({ height:'40px' }); // set height to 40px;

$('.class4').toggle(function() {
    $(this).animate({ height: cl4h });
}, function() {
    $(this).animate({ height: '40px' });
});
```

P.S.
Remove `height: 40px;` for the el `.class4` from your CSS

---

If you have to use more than one class here is a demo using tha jQuery `.data()` :

### [DEMO with .data()](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/vce6W/3/)

```
$('.class4').each(function(e) {
    var cl4h = $(this).height();    // get height of each element
    $(this).data('height', cl4h);   // and store it into .data (for each el)
});

$('.class4').css({height: '40px'}); // set heights to 40px on page load

$('.class4').toggle(function() {   
   $(this).animate({height: $(this).data('height') }); // call the el .data where is stored the el height
}, function() {
   $(this).animate({height: '40px'});
});
```

Comment: Hi @roXon, I am marking this as answer. The script is caching a variable to set the height. This is the original height of the first row only. But if i have a text lengthier than the first row, only a small porion of it is visible on toggle. you can see a working fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/blasteralfred/vce6W/1/ . do u hav any solution??

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/vce6W/2/ Just the first solution I immagined. There are other ways to achieve the same

Comment: And for your 'thanks bro' ... here is a demo usind the jQuery .data() [DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/vce6W/3/) It's more easy and 'fancy'.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `.css()` to change the `display` property, try having it as `display: block;` and instead use `.animate()` in the same place to animate the height of the element.

Comment: Hi @Sam, I marked roxon's answer. The script is caching a variable to set the height. This is the original height of the first row only. But if i have a text lengthier than the first row, only a small porion of it is visible on toggle. you can see a working fiddle here jsfiddle.net/blasteralfred/vce6W/1 . do u hav any solution??

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the `.fadeIn()` and `.fadeOut()` animations, using the `linear` easing option. This will give you a nice transition effect, as `.fadeIn()` (obviously) doesn't happen all at once.